# TornadoFX Combobox selectionModel.selectFirst on event

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

in tornadoFX components there are methods like disableWhen, enableWhen an so on. Where I can put some binding expression and it will change the component state. But I need a similar action for combobox selectFirst. And it should be triggered only once as soon as customers are not empty. For example:

```
combobox {
    disableWhen {
        Bindings.isEmpty(viewModel.customers)
    }

    selectionModel.selectFirst {
        Bindings.isNotEmpty(viewModel.customers)
    }
}
```